# sql connection string windows authentication c# winforms (not integrated)

Tags: c#, .net

I am making a simple c#.net winform application which will connect to sql server.
I wnat it to have 2 ways to connect- Windows Authentication and SQL server Authentication.

From what I found online I came up so far with:

```
public static void SetConnectionStringParams(string dbAddress, bool isWinAuth, string user, string password)
        {
            if (isWinAuth)
            {
                _connectionString =
                    string.Format(
                        "Data Source={0};Database = {1};Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=1000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=60",
                        dbAddress, DefaultDBname);
            }
            else
            {
                _connectionString =
                    string.Format(
                        "Data Source={0};Database = {1};User ID={2};Password={3};Max Pool Size=1000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=60",
                        dbAddress, DefaultDBname, user, password);
            }
        }
```

which works great, but I couldn't found how in case of Windows Auth I force require user and password instead of using the `Integrated Security=True`...

Is there an API that do that? if not, would appreciate guidance how to do it.

Thank you,

Comment: You misunderstand what Windows Authentication is. It means that the application will connect to the database using the *current Windows account*. Which is a **VERY** good thing as the users don't have to supply their credentials again. Think of it as SSO out of the box. You can't have Windows Authentication without that `Integrated Security` keyword

Comment: *Why* do you want to use SQL Server authentication *at all*? You *already* know who the user is. If you don't want to add individual accounts to the database, put all users in a Windows Group and add that group to the database instead

Comment: Yes, but I want it to force re-enter credentials from user upon connecting to sql server instead of using the current windows account (As a security precaution), is it possible? Thank you

Comment: That's not a security precaution, that's **weakening** security. Why would you want to do that? Besides, it's not SQL Server that checks the Windows account, it's *Windows*.  If you want increased security, make sure all computers on the network lock after X minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot

1. Ask user to enter windows username and password
2. Impersonate this user manually as by [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx) and fetch users Principal & Identity
3. Now fork new thread with this Principal/Identity to talk with database with *integrated security*
4. Flush user, identity and principal on job completion or on exception